# Understanding auto.arima resulting in (0,0,0) order

Tags: r, arima

I have the following time series for which I want to fit an ARIMA process:
[image]

The time series is stationary as the null hypothesis is rejected:

```
> adf.test(g_train)

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  g_train
Dickey-Fuller = -5.5232, Lag order = 17, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

When I train an ARIMA process with auto.arima, I have the following results:

```
> auto.arima(g_train)
Series: g_train 
ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
          mean
      142.6338
s.e.    0.4700

sigma^2 estimated as 1273:  log likelihood=-28761.11
AIC=57526.22   AICc=57526.23   BIC=57539.54
```

Why does it estimate the order to be (0,0,0)? How to interpret the results?

EDIT: it is getting weirder. It seems that auto.arima is given too many data and therefore is unable to compute a suitable model.

I have a total of 5760 values and the auto.arima is working if I pass it only a part of the array. There seems not to be any maximum length for the data.

```
auto.arima(g_train[1000:length(g_train)])
Series: g_train[1000:length(g_train)] 
ARIMA(4,1,3) 

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2     ar3     ar4      ma1     ma2      ma3
      2.5736  -1.9617  0.1803  0.2073  -1.4577  1.0505  -0.2284
s.e.  0.0437   0.1133  0.0985  0.0290   0.0437  0.0561   0.0371

sigma^2 estimated as 7.925e-05:  log likelihood=16008.3
AIC=-32000.6   AICc=-32000.57   BIC=-31948.86
```

EDIT2: Here the Acf plot of my data. We can clearly see a seasonal trend. Maybe the problem is coming from there?

[image]

Comment: It means that your data is white noise. See [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/5) for some explanation.

Comment: Well, you can clearly see from the plot that the data is not white noise. Any idea why it is happening ?

Comment: It is happening because the ARIMA(0, 0, 0) model was found to be the best by the `auto.arima` function. Are you positive your data is not white noise? Try the Ljung-Box test on your data `Box.test()` and look at the auto correlations `forecast::Acf()`, before ruling it out. If you still believe that your data is not white noise maybe you could try training your Arima model manually. See [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/7) for an explanation of how `auto.arima` works and how to train manually.

Comment: Here is the result of the Ljung-Box Test: X-squared = 5757.7, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16. From what I understand, there is indeed correlation in the data. I added the Acf plot to my question.

Comment: did you understand what was going on? i am in a similar situation

Comment: I ended up switching to Python and searching for the best order myself using cross-validation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `auto.arima` and specify if the series has a mean=0 or not

```
library(forecast)
auto.arima(x, allowmean=FALSE, allowdrift=FALSE, trace=TRUE)
```

`x` in this case is your time series data

Answer (score 1):

Probably I´m a little bit late, but I see 2 points that might be affecting this result.

1. Does the ts object contain the right frequency? Try `auto.arima(ts(as.numeric(AirPassengers), frequency = 4))` (wrong frequency) and `auto.arima(AirPassengers)` (right frequency) to see what I mean.
2. auto.arima goes up to a maximum order of (5, 2, 5)(2, 1, 2). Check the arguments starting with `max` to try different numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately I don't have access to this code anymore to try it out.